# How to make local system CA certificates known to Firefox?

Tags: debian, firefox, ssl, certificates, https

Recently, the CAcert root certificates have been removed from Debian (more precisely, from the `ca-certificates` package).  Since I want to keep them, I backed up the directory

```
/usr/share/ca-certificates/cacert.org/
```

containing two `.crt` files before the upgrade and copied it to

```
/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/cacert.org/
```

afterwards.  Then I ran `update-ca-certificates`:

```
# update-ca-certificates 
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs... 2 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d....
Adding debian:cacert.org_class3.pem
Adding debian:cacert.org_root.pem
done.
done.
```

It looks like all went well.  However, Firefox (Iceweasel) still refuses certificates signed by CAcert as untrusted.

Is there anything I missed?  Do I have to do something special to make Firefox actually re-read the system certificates?

Comment: I would say ==> http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/firefox-adding-trusted-ca/

Comment: Sure.  However, I'd like to add it as a system-wide setting.  The mechanics for this obviously exist; I'm just not sure how to use it properly.

Comment: As far as I know firefox does not use the trusted keystore of the sstem but it's own trusted keystore. but it seems possible with this article https://wiki.mozilla.org/NSS_Shared_DB_Howto

Answer (score 5):

Firefox works after a clean installation. If certificate database in `cert8.db` is deleted, it is regenerated on next Firefox start. This strongly suggests that there is a system-wide default storage of CA certs.

Firefox's source code [shows](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/master/security/nss/lib/ckfw/builtins/Makefile#L52) that built-in CA certs are in fact hard-coded into `firefox` executable. They reside in [security/nss/lib/ckfw/builtins/certdata.txt](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/master/security/nss/lib/ckfw/builtins/certdata.txt)

So there is no way to install a certificate system-wide. Beware that patching source code may bring up issues with intellectual property rights.

Comment: As for the last point, Firefox is free software, so there is no issue with modifying the source. Whether it is a good solution is another topic.